# NameError: function is not defined in Python

Tags: python, modularity

Please some help with the function

```
weightDiff
```

It works if I leave everything in a single .py file, however

- If I create a new file called functions.py and move the function in a new file
- The function is missing the weight value
- This is because the value weight is manually defined from the user by input()

```
import functions

firstName = input("Hi there, what's your name? ")
genderQuestion = input('Hello ' + firstName + ', are you a male or a female? ')
gender = genderQuestion.casefold()
age = input('How old are you? ')
weight = input("What's your weight in kg? ")
userData = [firstName, gender, age, weight]
userDetails = ['Name: ' + userData[0], 'Gender: ' + userData[1], 'Age: ' + userData[2], 'Weight: ' + userData[3] + 'kg']
print(functions.newLine())
print('Thanks for that. Below your details')
print('\n'.join(userDetails))

recommendedWeight = [89, 55]


def weightDiff(weight):
    if gender == 'male':
        return weight - recommendedWeight[0]
    else:
        return weight - recommendedWeight[1]


weightDifference = weightDiff(int(weight))
print(weightDifference)
```

What I want to achieve is a neat file, and a second file where I can store all my functions.

Comment: The reason you think it doesn't work is incorrect. If you are just going to use `import functions` then you will have to use `functions.weightDiff`. If you don't want to type all of that every time, import like this `from functions import weightDiff`.

Comment: It misses "recommendedWeight". If you move its definition to "functions" as well it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the issues is, but in general you put the function in the other file and import the desired function into your script where you'll use it.

Something like:

*functions.py*

```py
recommendedWeight = [89, 55]


def weightDiff(weight, gender):
    if gender == 'male':
        return weight - recommendedWeight[0]
    else:
        return weight - recommendedWeight[1]
```

File where you want to use the function.

*main.py*

```
from functions import weightDiff


# !!! Update this section to get input from user !!!
weight = 5
gender = "male"
result = weightDiff(weight, gender)
```

Comment: I want that the user insert the value (from the main file), if I do it so, the error is NameError: name 'weight' is not defined

Comment: Ok, just change the `weight = 5` part to get the value from the user, `weight = input("What's your weight in kg? ")`